# Is there a way to convert an OpenAPI specification to a spring cloud contract?

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, spring-cloud, openapi, spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying to convert an openAPI specification (written in yaml) into a spring cloud contract YAML DSL. Is there any plugin that could do this type of conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Please read this blog post on how to encorporate the yaml contract inside the openapi spec https://springframework.guru/defining-spring-cloud-contracts-in-open-api/

Comment: The SCC OA3 Converter combines the Spring cloud contract YAML DSL into OA3 extensions. All I need is to convert any Open API specification into DSL contracts

Comment: It's enough to add the section in your openapi to add a contract there

Comment: Does it work with the openapi-generator-maven-plugin, after adding the contract in openapi section?

Comment: From my understanding it's just providing an extension to the OpenAPI definition so it will work with any openapi compatible plugins.